# How can I abort a checkout if there are changes in the working directory in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Sometimes when I'm working on a bug fix, I want to go back to a known state (commit) to inspect something.

My working directory contains changes, and when I checkout to an older commit I do not want mercurial to try and merge the changes in. Instead, I'd like it to just abort the checkout (forcing me to shelve or discard).

Is there an option to solve this, or do I need to write my own hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, you need to write a hook for this. It is a simple hook, though:

```
[hooks]
preupdate = test -z "$(hg status --modified --added --removed --deleted)"
```

This calls `hg status` to find modified, added, removed, and deleted files. If any are found, the test returns a non-zero exit code and the update will stop.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the check switch when updating to a revision, it will abort if you have uncommited changes.

```
hg update --check
abort: uncommitted local changes
```

I'd advise you to always type out check rather than using the shorthand (-c), since if you accidentally type -C it'll happily update and throw out your changes.